# Convergence of numeric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am studying the following series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n (\log(n))(\log(\log(n)))}$$

With the integral test:

$$\int_2^{\infty} \dfrac{\text{dn}}{n (\log(n))(\log(\log(n)))} = \int_{\log(2)}^{\infty}\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\log(y)} = \int_{\log \log(2)}^{\infty} \dfrac{\text{d}\log y}{\log y} = \int_{\log \log(2)}^{\infty} \dfrac{\text{d}z}{z} = [\log(z)]^{\infty}_{\log \log(2)}$$ Therefore the integral diverges, so

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n (\log(n))(\log(\log(n)))}$$ diverges.

**Is that right?**

Comment: A small detail: shouldn't the series begin from $n=2$, as otherwise $\log(n)=0$ for $n=1$?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since  the series general term is monotonically decreasing (and positive for almost all $\;n\;$) , and

$$\left(\log\log n\right)'=\frac1{n\log n}$$ you can apply directly the integral test

$$\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x\log x\log\log x}=\left.\lim_{b\to\infty}\log\log\log x\right|_2^b$$

and the series diverges since the above limit doesn't exist finitely.

Answer (score 0):

No, $n((log(n))(log(log(n))) < nlog(n)^2\implies \frac{1}{n((log(n))(log(log(n)))}>\frac{1}{nlog(n)^2}$, so the comparison test won't imply convergence. (You have to show $\frac{1}{n((log(n))(log(log(n)))}$ is LESS than a known convergent series to apply the comparison test).

You can prove that this series diverges via the integral test, as $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x((log(x))(log(log(x)))}dx$, exists. just make the substitution $u=x(log(x))$, and then a second substitution $u'=\frac{1}{log(x)}$

Comment: Thank, you, I think I want too fast and skipped a step, Thanks a lot

Comment: I think the series (and the integral) diverge.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, i don't know why i typed converge, I fixed it in my edit.